# openpyxl - Find the maximum length of a cell for each column

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

It's my first time to use openpyxl. I want to know the size of the longest cell for each column in Excel. I tried hard to write the code, but the output is in row, and even that doesn't come out correctly. How can I fix it what I want? If you know, please reply, thank you

```
import openpyxl

filepath = "test.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)

ws = wb.active

max_row = ws.max_row
max_column = ws.max_column


for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    max_length = 0
    for j in range(1, max_column + 1):
        try:
            if len(str(ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(ws.cell(row=i, column=j).value)
        except:
            pass
    print(max_length)
```

Comment: You are iterating over the rows first, then the columns. It should be the other way round.

Comment: Use `ws.iter_cols()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the `ws.iter_cols()`, like @CharlieClark mentioned in the comments. Here's an example:

```
maxLen = float('-inf')
columns = sht.iter_cols(2, 2) # The (2, 2) is the mincol to maxcol, including the max column itself, e.g. if you want to iterate through column 7, you do (7, 7)
for col in columns:
    for cellRow in col: #cellRow is the specific cell, not its value
        maxLen = len(cellRow.value) if len(cellRow.value) > maxLen else maxLen #Sets maxLen to the length of cellRow.value if it is larger than maxLen.
```